# Yii 2 Gridview - Search Query generates ambiguous fields

Tags: mysql, gridview, yii2

I am generating related records search query for Gridview use

I get this error :
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'dbowner' in where clause is ambiguous
The SQL being executed was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tbl_iolcalculation` LEFT JOIN `tbl_iolcalculation` `patient` ON `tbl_iolcalculation`.`patient_id` = `patient`.`id` WHERE (`dbowner`=1) AND (`dbowner`=1)

I have two related models 1) iolcalculation and patient - each iolcalculation has one patient (iolcalculation.patient_id -> patient.id)

The relevant code in my model IolCalculationSearch is :

```
public function search($params)
{
    $query = IolCalculation::find();

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);
    $dataProvider->sort->attributes['patient.lastname'] = [
          'asc' => ['patient.lastname' => SORT_ASC],
          'desc' => ['patient.lastname' => SORT_DESC],
     ];

    $query->joinWith(['patient'=> function($query) { $query->from(['patient'=>'tbl_iolcalculation']); } ]); 

    if (!($this->load($params) && $this->validate())) {
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    $query->andFilterWhere([
        'id' => $this->id,
        'patient_id' => $this->patient_id,
        'preop_id' => $this->preop_id,
        'calculation_date' => $this->calculation_date,
        'iol_calculated' => $this->iol_calculated,
```

The reason this error is generated is that each model has an override to the default Where clause as follows,  the reason being that multiple users data needs to be segregated from other users, by the field dbowner:

```
 public static function defaultWhere($query) {
    parent::init();
    $session = new Session();
    $session->open();

    $query->andWhere(['t.dbowner' => $session['dbowner']]);
 }
```

this is defined in a base model extending ActiveRecord, and then all working models extend this base model

How Can I resolve this ambiguous reference in the MySQL code?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

```
$query->andFilterWhere([
    // previous filters
    self::tableName() . '.structure_id' => $this->structure_id,
    // next filters
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, that you are searching for table aliases.
(https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/2377)

Like this, of course you have to change the rest of your code:

```
$query->joinWith(['patient'=> function($query) { $query->from(['patient p2'=>'tbl_iolcalculation']); } ]);
```

Comment: That results in the same error with just p2 added: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'dbowner' in where clause is ambiguous
The SQL being executed was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tbl_iolcalculation` LEFT JOIN `tbl_iolcalculation` `patient p2` ON `tbl_iolcalculation`.`patient_id` = `patient p2`.`id` WHERE (`dbowner`=1) AND (`dbowner`=1)  ****** What I need is to add the aliases to the `downer` columns somehow - Thanks for your consideration

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can get this to work is to override the default scope find I had set up for most models, so that it includes the actual table name as follows - in my model definition:

```
public static function find() {
    $session = new Session();
    $session->open();
    return parent::find()->where(['tbl_iolcalculation.dbowner'=> $session['dbowner']]);
}
```

There may be a more elegant way using aliases, so any advice would be appreciated - would be nice to add aliases to where clauses, and I saw that they are working on this....